# Recursive binary search function missing something? (C)

Tags: c, function, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to make a function that does a binary search on a sorted array. I've checked everything, and everything works correctly, except one thing:

If I don't put a return statement in the end of the function, not surrounded by If's, It won't build my program. If I put 'return 0', it would always return 0, no matter what. If I'll do the same with 1, it would always return 1, and I can't see where is my problem. Would love some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4
int search_matrix(int a[N][N], int x);
int binsearch(int a[], int x, int low, int high);
int main(){
    int a[N][N];
    printf("Please Enter Matrix : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }//forj
    }//fori
    printf("Please enter x : \n");
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("%d\n",search_matrix(a,x));
    return 0;
}
int search_matrix(int a[N][N], int x){
    if(x>a[0][N-1]||x<a[N-1][0])
        return 0;

    int savedIndex=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(x>a[i][0]){
            savedIndex=i;
            break;
        }
    }//for

    return(binsearch(a[savedIndex],x,0,N));

}//search_matrix

//------- THE PROBLEMATIC FUNCTION! ---------
int binsearch(int a[], int x, int low, int high) {
   int mid;
   if (low > high)
      return 0;
   mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (x == a[mid]) {
      return 1;
   } else if (x < a[mid]) {
      binsearch(a, x, low, mid - 1);
   } else {
      binsearch(a, x, mid + 1, high);
   }


}
```

Comment: `binsearch(a, x, low, mid - 1);` --> `return binsearch(a, x, low, mid - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define N 4
    int search_matrix(int a[N][N], int x);
    int binsearch(int a[], int x, int low, int high);
    int main(){
        int a[N][N], i, j;
        printf("Please Enter Matrix : \n");
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }//forj
        }//fori
        printf("Please enter x : \n");
        int x;
        scanf("%d",&x);

        printf("%d\n",search_matrix(a,x));
        return 0;
    }
    int search_matrix(int a[N][N], int x){
        if(x>a[0][N-1]||x<a[N-1][0])
            return 0;

        int savedIndex=0, i;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(x>a[i][0]){
                savedIndex=i;
                break;
            }
        }//for

        return(binsearch(a[savedIndex],x,0,N));

    }//search_matrix

    //------- THE PROBLEMATIC FUNCTION! ---------
    int binsearch(int a[], int x, int low, int high) {
       int mid;
       if (low > high)
          return 0;
       mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (x == a[mid]) {
          return 1;
       } else if (x < a[mid]) {
          binsearch(a, x, low, mid - 1);
       } else {
          binsearch(a, x, mid + 1, high);
       }


    }
```